# Склоняется ли слово "тонфа"?

Tags: морфология

Есть такое японское оружие в виде дубинок с рукоятками — тонфа. И я не могу понять, склоняется ли это слово по падежам и числам? То есть, когда речь идет о двух дубинках, будет "тонфы" или все равно "тонфа"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 сакур**ы**, 2 гейш**и**, 2 катан**ы** и т. д. Нет никакой причины для того, чтобы тонфа выбивалась из этого списка. Так что по всем признакам тонфа должна склонятся по 1 склонению, без каких либо ограничений. Судя по практике применения слова в интернете, именно эту картину мы и наблюдаем в речи.