# И снова о тонфа(х)

Tags: заимствования, морфология

Этот вопрос на форуме уже поднимался. Марк Из сказал, что слово "тонфа" — такое же, как "катана" или "гейша", то есть, женского рода первого склонения, с чем я соглашаюсь. Но вчера у меня состоялся разговор с филологом на эту тему. Так вот, она уверяет, что "тонфа" все-таки не изменяется вообще, и ссылается на английские тексты, где, например, "катана" во множественном числе пишется "katanas", а вот "тонфа" — без окончания множественного числа S. И [вот это](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/19430/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B0) обсуждение в качестве аргумента ее не убедило.
Поэтому мне бы хотелось услышать мнения и других специалистов на эту тему. Согласны ли они с точкой зрения Марк Иза (или Макра Из — как правильно?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы бы лучше аргументы филолога поподробнее изложили. 
А что в интернете есть - это сами знаете...
Я правильно понял, что её логика сводится к тому, что на английском слово не имеет множественного числа?

Так ли оно - не знаю. Но это никак не связано с русской грамматикой. "У советских собственная гордость." захотим - будем склонять. И мы действительно крепко захотели.
В русском все слова на -а склоняются за исключением некоторых собственных, аббревиатур и односложных типа Бра, или Фа (нота). И "хитрые" типа Боа, Фейхоа и кечуа (индейцы) и т.п. Кажется, всё...

Что касается вопроса на английском форуме, то ответа ждать придется долго. Я ответа не знаю, а с другими отвечальщиками там пока не очень... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Кроме отдельных иностранных имён собственных (Дюма, Гоа) я вообще не могу вспомнить в русском языке несклоняемых существительных заканчивающихся на "-а".

Какое отношение имеет склонение "tonfa" в английских текстах, к русскому слову, заимствованному из японского языка, я не знаю. Во французском, немецком, польском и словенском, если что, "тонфа" вполне себе склоняется (источник: статьи Википедии на этих языках). Но всё это к русской "тонфе" не имеет никакого отношения. У нас свои тараканы в языке, у них - свои.

Так как однозначной словарной нормы у данного слова нет, то ориентироваться приходится на частотность употребления, благо с появлением интернета это сделать нетрудно. Итак, Гугл выдаёт:

> Запрос *"тонфа"* - 120 000 результатов
> Запрос *"тонфой"* - 36 000 результатов (30% от начальной формы)
> Запрос *"тонфы"* - 19 500 результатов (16,25% от Н.ф.)

По Яндексу:

> *"тонфа"* - 61 тыс. ответов
> *"тонфой"* - 5 тыс. ответов (8,2% от Н.ф.)
> *"тонфы"* - 13 тыс. ответов (21,3% от Н.ф.)

Это говорит о том, что русскоязычные носители данного слова, вполне активно его склоняют по 1 склонению, о чём я и писал в своём первом ответе.

О причинах отсутствие формы множественного числа в английском лучше задать на соответствующем форуме. [Ссылка](http://english.sezn.ru/)

P.S. "Что имя, друг? Ведь роза пахнет розой, хоть розой назови её, хоть нет". Ник мой можно произносить и так и так.